# Automate assignment queue with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that get updated every weeknight.

Someone then pull the table down, assigns values where the QueueT is null based on the number already assigned out and the type.

Think of it as a queueing system to even out workflow as evenly as possible.

Im stuck on attempting to automate the assignment piece

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a657/1

shows how much is assigned to each person, but how would i got about updating the table to assign each person based on type and even the assignments out as much as possible?

```
  -- create temp table code if needed

create table #tempqueue

(
    QueueT varchar(20)
    ,Type varchar(20)
)

insert into #tempqueue
(
    QueueT 
    ,Type 
)

values
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type2'),
( 'null' , 'type2'),
( 'tim' , 'type1'),
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'jill' , 'type2'),
( 'jack' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type1'),
( 'null' , 'type2'),
( 'null' , 'type2'),
( 'null' , 'type2')


select


    QueueT 
    ,type
    ,count(Type) counttype

from #tempqueue


group by 
    QueueT 
    ,type
```

Comment: Is `null` a person, or can be treated as a person? (Actually, a string value of "null" is a bad idea - too easily confused with the database value `null`. Perhaps use 'none' instead).

Comment: @Turophile its an actual null, i wrote the create table quickly and didnt notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a unique id for the table so each record can be updated individually:

```
create table tempqueue

(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,QueueT varchar(20)
    ,Type varchar(20)
)
```

Then you can update it using a couple sub queries, `min`, `count`, and the `row_number` windowed function:

```
create table tempqueue

(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,QueueT varchar(20)
    ,Type varchar(20)
)

insert into tempqueue
(
    QueueT 
    ,Type 
)

values
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type3'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type2'),
( null , 'type2'),
( 'tim' , 'type1'),
( 'bob' , 'type1'),
( 'jill' , 'type2'),
( 'jack' , 'type2'),
( 'john' , 'type2'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type1'),
( null , 'type2'),
( null , 'type2'),
( null , 'type2')

-- loop through records until no records are updated
declare @rows_updated int = 1
while @rows_updated > 0
    begin
        update t
            set t.QueueT = u.QueueT
            from tempqueue t
                -- get min record id per type where QueueT is null
                inner join (select Type,min(id) id
                            from tempqueue
                            where QueueT is null
                            group by Type) id
                    on id.Type = t.Type
                    and id.id = t.id
                -- get QueueT for each Type with the least count
                inner join (select QueueT,Type,
                                row_number() over(partition by Type order by cnt) lst
                            from (select QueueT,Type,count(*) cnt
                                  from tempqueue
                                  where QueueT is not null
                                  group by QueueT,Type)c)u
                    on u.Type = id.Type
                    and u.lst = 1
            set @rows_updated = @@rowcount
    end

select QueueT,Type,count(*) cnt
from tempqueue
group by QueueT,Type
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c0f6/1)

Comment: thanks it works beautifully.

one question - if there are no matches, how can i prevent an infinite loop?

Comment: I have updated the query and SQL FIDDLE to use @@rowcount to determine if any rows were updated. If 0 rows are updated, the loop ends. I added a type 3 to demonstrate this, and I replaced the 'null' strings with null values in light of comments on your question.